# Ошибка при установке PyQt4 на PyCharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, pip, pyqt4

[image: Ошибка при инсталляции PyQt4]

Вроде  как на `pip` ругается, но он установлен. Пробовал с разными версиями Python в качестве интерпретатора в настройках проекта. Пробовал отдельный `virtualenv` создавать под проект. Что ещё может быть не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В терминале ввести:

```
apt-cache search pyqt
sudo apt-get install python-qt4
```

Comment: `python-qt4 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
`, но в PyCharm в списке установленных пакетов для выбранной версии Python - PyQt4 не отображается

Comment: Стоит только одна версия питона? А если в коде попытаться импортировать `from PyQt4.QtGui import *` ругается интерпретатор?

Comment: переустановил пакеты под Python 3.5 - подчёркивание PyQt устранилось и программа запускается. Пока будем считать, что вопрос закрыт.